# Contour plot using rstudio

Tags: r

I have data in this format i.e for every month the hourly data for 24 hours

```
Hours  Months

0      Jan   Feb . . . . Dec

1      20.3              109

2      45.67             104

3      34.8               .

.      .                  .

.      .                  .

24     .                  110
```

I want to make a contour plot using this in rstudio. How can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what didn't work as expected?

Comment: I am not understanding how to give the data as an input. 
I have tried using plotly function but I could not give the Z co -ordinates appropriately.